# showing $\inf\{|s_n| : n ∈ N\} > 0$ for a convergent sequence of real numbers

Tags: analysis

My book proves this as one of their examples which is Let $(s_n)$ be a convergent sequence of real numbers such that $s_n \ne 0$ for all $n ∈ N$ and $\lim s_n = s \neq 0$. Prove $\inf\{|s_n| : n ∈ N\} > 0$.

The proof goes like this 
Let  $\epsilon= |s|/2>0$. Since $\lim s_n = s$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that
$n > N$ implies $|s_n − s| <|s|/2$. Now $n > N$ implies $|s_n| ≥|s|/2$ since otherwise the triangle inequality would imply $|s| = |s − s_n + s_n| ≤ |s − s_n| + |s_n| <|s|/2+|s|/2= |s|$
which is absurd. If we set $m=min\{|s|/2,|s_1|,|s_2|,..,|s_N|\}$ then we clearly have $m> 0$ and $|s_n| ≥ m$ for all $n ∈ N$ .Thus $inf\{|s_n| : n ∈ N\} ≥ m> 0$, as desired.

What I don't get is how they figured out that  $\epsilon= |s|/2>0$ ? I understand that "most" of the terms of $s_n$ are within $1/2|s|$ but why can I still use the fact that  $|s_n| ≥|s|/2$?

Comment: Is this exactly how this is stated, at first glance the condition that $s_n = 0 \; \forall \; n \in \mathbb{N}$ seems to contradict that $s_n \to s \neq 0$

Comment: Sorry I forgot to edit that.

Comment: This question still seems vague - I don't see how the proof plays out

Comment: I added the complete proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment I'm unsure as to how they are doing their proof but I will give my idea...

Given that $s_n \to s \neq 0$ and that $s_n \neq 0 \; \forall \; n \in \mathbb{N}$ we know that $s_n$ will never vanish (become 0). So if we assume that $\inf \{ \lvert s_n \rvert \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \} = 0$ then $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $s_N = 0$ however this contradicts that $s_n$ never vanishes. Now it's clear that $\lvert s_n \rvert \ge 0$ but since $\lvert s_n \rvert \neq 0$ it follows that $\lvert s_n \rvert > 0$ so the $\inf\{\lvert s_n\rvert \} > 0$ as well.

---

Now to answer exactly what you're asking, they use $\lvert s \rvert / 2$ so that they can use the triangle equality to show that $s_n \ge \lvert s \rvert / 2$. If you don't understand the triangle inequality business, if you combine the inequalities they use you get that $\lvert s \rvert < \lvert s \rvert$ which is pretty absurd :P

---

EDIT:

It should be mentioned that the reason that there's some $s_N$ above so that $s_N = 0$ is because if there wasn't, then there would be some sequence of points $\{\lvert s_k \rvert\}_k$ so that $\lvert s_k \rvert \to 0$. This must mean there's some subsequence $\lvert s_{n_i} \rvert \to 0$ (otherwise there would be some biggest index $K$ that is in the indices of $s_k$ thus there would only be a finite number of elements, telling us that one of them would have to be $0$) which in turn tells us $s_n \to 0$ but this contradicts that $s \neq 0$.

Really, looking back this argument can be summed up by:

- Assume $\inf$ is $0$, find that either $\exists N$ so that $s_N = 0$ or that $s_n \to 0$ (this requirement that one of these holds is shown above)
- Show that $0$ is a lower bound on the set
- Use the above two facts to conclude that $\inf > 0$

Comment: Let me know if things are still unclear - I personally feel like their proof is a bit of overkill

Comment: Oh yeah most of it makes sense except for that little part of figuring out how they got epsilon. I'm guessing they figured it out by observation.

Comment: @user60887 yea seems that way, simply for that inequality they wanted. I still personally like my proof better xD

Comment: yeah your proof is much simpler and neat. Thanks.

Comment: @user60887 glad to help!

Comment: Why can we  conclude that if inf{$|s_n| n \in N$} = 0 , then there will exist N so that $s_N = 0 $ ?

Comment: @nerdy check out my edit, not sure why I left this out originally